# Django: Filter combined columns with tuple

Tags: python, django, filter

How do I generate this type of `where` clause using the Django ORM?

```
where (datetime, id) < (%last_datetime, %last_id)
```

**Background**

I have a model like this:

```
class Messages(models.Model):
  # Implicit "id" serial primary key
  datetime = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
  message = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
```

I sort the messages by `datetime` and use the `id` as a tie breaker for consistent sorting when multiple messages have the same `datetime` with:

```
Messages.objects.order_by('datetime', 'id')
```

Now I need to filter out messages that were ordered before a given known message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit convoluted, but I suppose this would work:

```
Messages.objects.filter(datetime__lte=x).exclude(datetime=x, id__gt=y)
```

Comment: Thank you. I had come up with a similar solution using `Q` objects. Before accepting, I'll wait a bit to see if anyone knows of a simpler solution and I'll check if it generates the desired type of query (or one that has similar performance).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `objects.filter()`:

```
relevant_messages = Messages.objects.filter(datetime__range=[start_date_string, end_date_string])
```

I'm also pretty sure you can chain your `order_by()` and `filter()` calls together:

```
relevant_messages = Messages.objects.order_by('datetime', 'id').filter(datetime__range=[start_date_string, end_date_string])
```

Comment: Thank you, but this won't work because it doesn't include the `id` in the filter. The `where` clause I showed works by combining values into relations and then comparing the relations. It's much like comparing tuples in Python.